# unix copy/download progress status update

Tags: linux, unix, command, command-prompt, scp

When we `scp` files from a machine to another machine. It provides us progress status which include information like: `percentage completed`, `upload rate` and `time to finish`. Same thing happens with `curl` when you download a file using `-O` option.

**My Question :** Usually output (**STDOUT**) is static in nature, but this status bar keep on updating continuously `in-place`. How does command prompts implement this logic?

My guess : They clear the line and rewrite it again, I am looking for little more information. (I could be potentially wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done very simply by using the carriage-return character (control-M) instead of newline between lines.  You can try it yourself with:

```
echo -e 'abcdef\rxxx'
```

where `\r` is how carriage-return is usually entered in strings.  The above command appears as `xxxdef` on your terminal because the carriage-return 
has moved back to the start of the line, without going down one line, and overwritten the "abc" at the start.

You can check this for your `scp` command by capturing the output into a file and looking at the data. For example:

```
script -c 'scp /a/very/big/file someremote:'
```

will create a file `typescript` with a copy of the progress lines. You can look at the control characters in this file with

```
cat -vet typescript
```

which will show the carriage-returns as `^M`, i.e. control-M, and the newlines as `$`.

Comment: The `echo` example works. I try to run this in for loop, objective was to write multiple time on the same line. But it prints as many time loop runs. Even I tried to put `\r` at the end of the string. `for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo -e 'abcdef\rxxx\r'; done;`

Comment: By default, `echo` adds a newline to the end of the string. You can suppress this with option `-n`.

Comment: @meuh, the new line has only been shown as `$` in some unix (and cp/m) editors, to mark where the end of line was, but it has no relation to it.

Comment: @LuisColorado I was referring to the  `cat -e` option, which according to the man page on my system means "display $ at end of each line".

Comment: @meuh, `cat(1)` displays `$` to mark lines with possible blanks at the end, so you can see where the end of line is, but that doesn't mean there's any relation from an *end of line* to the `$` char.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done *via* escape sequences, char sequences that can control different capabilities of the terminal. See [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for example. There exists different libraries to handle these in a kind of portable way : `curses`, `ncurses`, etc, at least in Unix-like world.

Comment: Indeed, `curses` is there to cope with different kinds of escape sequences.  Not all terminals use the same escape sequences.  ANSI escape sequences are only one flavour, but you'll get a screen garbled if you try to use ANSI escapes with an HP terminal or others (at some time, when `curses` was invented, even one installation could have more than 10 different classes of terminals, each having its own set of scape sequences)  By the way, the solution given by @meuh is good, and don't involve complicated things like escape sequences.